# How to listen iframe keydown event with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, keydown

I want to listen for a keydown event of an iframe in reactjs. In my iframe i have video embedded. Now when the video is playing i want to handle keyboard events.Can any one please help me how to listen for keyboard events. This is my code

```
class VideoDetail extends Component {

videoLoad(e) {
    console.log('videoLoaded');
    this.videoFrame.addEventListener('keydown',this.onVideoDown);
}

onVideoDown(e) {
    console.log('key pressed'); // This is not invoking
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.videoFrame);
}
render() {
    const video = this.props.video;
    if (!video) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    const videoId = video.id.videoId;
    const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;
    return (
        <div className="video-detail col-md-8">
            <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe ref={(iframe) => { this.videoFrame = iframe; console.log(iframe); }} className="embed-responsive-item" src={url} onLoad={(e) => this.videoLoad(e)}></iframe>
            </div>
            <div className="details">
                <div>{video.snippet.title}</div>
                <div>{video.snippet.description}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the iframe `keydown` event with `iframe.contentWindow.document` as below using either `e.target` or `this.videoFrame` with the `ref`.

**Modified code**

```
videoLoad(e) {
    console.log('videoLoaded');
    var iframe = e.target; // it is equal to "this.videoFrame" and so, you can avoid using "ref"
    //this.videoFrame.addEventListener('keydown',this.onVideoDown);
    iframe.contentWindow.document.addEventListener('keydown', this.onVideoDown);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply aruna. I am getting this error after adding your line.Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: @Trinu, This is coming under `Same-origin security policy` as you are trying to access one domain from another domain using javascript. If both domains are same, then the above code will work without any issues otherwise you have to disable the browser security if you are just creating the page for testing only. Please have a look at this url, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/7055233

Comment: i have executed this command in osx -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir. This time i am not getting error but keydown event is not firing.. unable to listen the keydown event.

Comment: I hope you tried this, `$ open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir` in OSX

Comment: Can you give me a sample data used for `this.props.video` ?

Comment: Its just an object contains id...  const url = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`; that url i am using in iframe src={url} you can try with any youtube id url = https://www.youtube.com/embed/-VMgTCnFGys

Comment: @Trinu, I checked this in my windows machine and works as expected without any issues. I can see `key pressed` printed in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142395/discussion-between-trinu-and-aruna).

Comment: Thanks Aruna its working.. Thanks a lot for your answer.